# What is the difference between a Hamiltonian Path and a Hamiltonian Cycle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, hamiltonian-path

The title says it all. I've seen confusing definitions of this, and would appreciate if someone can succinctly clear this up with definitions and examples.

Comment: A cycle is, with an abuse of notation, a closed polygon, while a path is a polygonal-line, open...

Comment: And this is true for every path/cycle e.g. Eulerian path...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cycle starts and ends in the same vertex, but the path does not.

Comment: Oh! I feel stupid for asking this now! For some reason I was getting confused reading the formal definitions.... Thanks

Comment: @Agile_Eagle Note that this also means that in a graph with $n$ vertices, a Ham-path has $n-1$ edges, while a Ham-cycle has $n$ edges.

Comment: Arguably you should merely say that a Hamiltonian cycle includes an edge from the end node to the start node, since the essence of a Hamiltonian traverse is that the nodes are only visited once. I’m not sure anyone worries about such minor technicalities though.

Answer (score 2):

Hamiltonian cycle = a cycle (path ending in the same vertex it starts) that visits every vertex ($ n $ edges);
Hamiltonian path= a path that visits every vertex ($ n  - 1 $ edges).

In the graph represented by the matrix of adiacence:

```
01001
10100
01010
00101
10010
```

We have `1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5` or `1 - 5 - 4 - 3 - 2` Hamiltonian paths.
Also, `1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 1` is a Hamiltonian cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Hamiltonian path is a path in an undirected or directed graph that visits each vertex exactly once
Hamiltonian cycle is a Hamiltonian path that is a cycle, and a cycle is closed trail in which the “first vertex = last vertex” is
the only vertex that is repeated.
For more info https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/cgt_online/book/section05.03.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path